# Is it possible for HTML5 video source to have #

Tags: html, video

Following does not work, as '#' is not allowed. Other characters are ok.

When page with video is loaded, video does not show. After removing "#", it works.

```
  <video id="video" defaultMuted autoplay playsinline controls>
    <source src="/media/movie/Crash,()<>{}@&*&(_) Course #15.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
```

Is it possible to keep '#' in video file, so that video file name is can be more descriptive.

Comment: everything after a `#` is an anchor link - https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3 - so it actually sees the URL only up to that point and then looks for the #15.mp4 part within the page source

Comment: You can percent encode it

Answer (score 1):

[RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2) defines certain characters as reserved, hence you cannot use them directly. However, you can "percent encode" the URL and it should work.

```
!    #    $    &    '    (    )    *    +    ,    /    :    ;    =    ?    @    [    ]
%21  %23  %24  %26  %27  %28  %29  %2A  %2B  %2C  %2F  %3A  %3B  %3D  %3F  %40  %5B  %5D

Space is %20.
```

This would lead to

```
%2Fmedia%2Fmovie%2FCrash%2C%28%29%3C%3E%7B%7D%40%26%2A%26%28_%29%20Course%20%2315.mp4`
```

or simpler

```
/media/movie/Crash%2C%28%29%3C%3E%7B%7D%40%26%2A%26%28_%29%20Course%20%2315.mp4
```

for your link.

Answer (score 0):

**#** Is a special character and needs to be [encoded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/percent-encoding). Your file name also includes **&** which immediately stands out as a special character.

A fully safe and encoded version would look like

```
<video id="video" defaultMuted autoplay playsinline controls>
  <source src="/media/movie/Crash%2C%28%29%3C%3E%7B%7D%40%26%2A%26%28_%29%20Course%20%2315%0A.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

In general you should only use alpha numeric characters with the addition of underscores (_) or hyphens (-) in file names and links. This will ensure maximum compatability across file systems and avoid the need for URL Encoding.

So yes it's possible, but not advisable. There are literally thousands of ways to keep the filename meaningful without using reserved characters.